# display single row for multiple null values row having same emp in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
CCNo    Name  Jan    Feb   Mar   Apr   May  Jun  Jul   Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  Dec    
C121    Ram   1200  NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL NULL  NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL
C121    Ram   NULL  2500  NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL NULL  NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL 
C121    Ram   NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL  1470  NULL NULL  NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL  
F254    RAJ    5000 NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL
```

I want repeated rows with null values to be removed for the same employee with one record displaying monthwise salary instead of one one rows for one one month.

I need a SQL Server query for this

Answer (score 2):

Try this query

```
SELECT
  CCNo,
  Name,
  SUM([Jan]) [Jan],
  SUM([Feb]) [Feb],
  SUM([Mar]) [Mar],
  ...
  SUM([Dec]) [Dec]
FROM [Your Table]
GROUP BY CCNo,Name
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir.. You have made my day  as I was struggling to do so since last 3-4 days.. Once again thanks..

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
DECLARE @TAB TABLE (CCNO VARCHAR(10), [NAME] VARCHAR(100), JAN MONEY, FEB MONEY, MAR MONEY, APR MONEY, MAY MONEY, JUN MONEY, JUL MONEY, AUG MONEY, SEP MONEY, OCT MONEY, NOV MONEY, [DEC] MONEY)
INSERT INTO @TAB
SELECT 'C121',    'RAM',  1200  ,NULL  ,NULL  ,NULL  ,NULL  ,NULL ,NULL  ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C121',    'RAM',  NULL  ,2500  ,NULL  ,NULL  ,NULL  ,NULL ,NULL  ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C121',    'RAM',  NULL  ,NULL  ,NULL  ,NULL  ,1470  ,NULL ,NULL  ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL  UNION ALL
SELECT 'F254',    'RAJ',   5000 ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL

SELECT CCNO, [NAME], [MONTH], SALARY FROM @TAB
UNPIVOT 
(
    SALARY
    FOR
    [MONTH] IN ([JAN] , [FEB] , [MAR] , [APR] , [MAY] , [JUN] , [JUL] , [AUG] , [SEP] , [OCT] , [NOV], [DEC])
)UPV
ORDER BY 1
```

HTH!

Thanks.